# Is it possible to set the length of an OfflineAudioContext after creation/just before rendering?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

in a web audio project, I have an online- and an offline audio context, the latter one mirroring the former. The problem is, I don't know the final length of the audio I want to generate, but I have several `AudioWorklets` that need to be created beforehand, so they can receive user input, etc.

So when calling `startRendering` on the offline context, it just renders the length specified at creation time.

The `length` property seems to be read-only.

Is there really no way to set the length just before rendering ?

Best,
N

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do this. But there is an issue filed on the spec to enable incremental rendering. Maybe you can add your use case there.

https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/2445

For now it might work if you create proxies for your worklets that collect the user input upfront before you create the actual `OfflineAudioContext` with the real worklets.

Comment: Oof that's what I was afraid of ... that is really inconvenient. Especially as larger audio files are part of the user input (the user can add samples, etc).